# How do I add more balls and make them have a different starting position? Is that even possible with my aproach?

Tags: java

Im trying to create a "bouncingBall" screensaver-type of program. And Im having difficulty programming more balls/ovals, and make them have a random starting point. I want to keep my approach to this problem as it is, if that is possible and is not going to be too complicated. My first question, Im new to programming, if this way is entirely wrong, please do tell. Thank you for answers.

```
public class Game {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Spillvindu();
  }
}

public class Spillvindu extends JFrame {

  private Anothergame game;

  Spillvindu() {
    add(game = new Anothergame());
    game.lagSpillVindu();
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(800, 600);
  }
}

public class Anothergame extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

  void lagSpillVindu() {
    Timer t = new Timer(10, this);
    t.start();
  }
  private int ballYSpeed = 5;

  private int ballXSpeed = 5;

  private int ballX;

  private int ballY;

  private static Random random = new Random(800);

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 40, 40);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    ballX = ballX + ballXSpeed;
    ballY = ballY + ballYSpeed;
    if (ballY >= 520) {
      ballYSpeed = - 5;
    }
    if (ballX >= 730) {
      ballXSpeed = - 5;
    }
    if (ballX <= 0) {
      ballXSpeed = 5;
    }
    if (ballY <= 0) {
      ballYSpeed = 5;
    }
    repaint();
  }
}
```

Comment: Make a `Ball` class and then create a collection (array, list, etc) of `Ball`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
class Ball {
  private int ballX;
  private int ballY;
  private int ballWidth;
  private int ballHeight;

  Ball(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    ballX = x;
    ballY = y
    ballWidth = width;
    ballHeight = height;
  }
  // ... (add getter methods)
}
```

then you would have something like:

```
List<Ball> balls = getBalls(); // Create a bunch of balls somehow
// ...
for (Ball ball : balls) {
  // update the balls position
}
```

then render them:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
  g.fillRect(0,0, 800, 600);
  g.setColor(Color.black)
  for (Ball b : balls)
    g.fillOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Im sorry, but I didnt get it to work.I really tried, but at this point in time im probably going need a little more specifics. Im still trying to learn this. Anyway, thanks for helping me out!